# Perl: Index of data structure not allowed by compiler

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Im assigning the from and to times to the first and last entry below

```
my $from_time = $self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}->[0]->{'epochtime'};
print "$from_time";
my $to_time = $#{$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}->{'ulsaStats'}}->{'epochtime'};
print "FROM is $from_time to is $to_time";
```

But this gives the following error (refers to the first 2 lines)

```
Use of uninitialized value $from_time in string at /data/ddp/current/analysis/TOR/elasticsearch/handlers/UlsaSpectrumAnalyser.pm line 103.
Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at /data/ddp/current/analysis/TOR/elasticsearch/handlers/UlsaSpectrumAnalyser.pm line 104.
```

Comment: One of the keys or indexes in your data structure that you're using, doesn't exist. But (obviously, I'd hope) without seeing that data structure, we have no chance at all of working out what the problem is.

Comment: Mostl likely, `$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}{'ulsaStats'} = @a;` was used instead of `$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}{'ulsaStats'} = \@a;`

Comment: `$#{...}->{...}` doesn't look right: `$#{...}` returns an integer (the last index of the arrayref),  so the `->{...}` can't work and should say something like `Can't use string ("0") as a HASH ref...` if your array has only one element. Moreover, given the order of your warning/error: first, `$from_time` not initialized in string (your 2nd line), it seems likely that the error ("can't use string...") comes from the 3rd line.

Answer (score 2):

The error message means that one of these expressions has the value of "0":

```
$self
$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}
$self->{'r_instrDataEvent'}{'ulsaStats'}[0]
```

You were clearly not expecting the value of this expression to be "0", so you have some debugging to do upstream.

Are you familiar with the perl debugger (`perl -d ...`)? The debugger would let you run the code to the problematic line above and then inspect those expressions to see exactly where your expectations are not being met.